# How to use MapBuilder in kotlin and add all values?

Tags: java, arrays, kotlin

I am trying to convert/add below java code in bamboo spec in kotlin but geeting error.Can someone let me know how to use it in KOTLIN?How to use mapbuilder in kotlin which they are using in java.

```
new AnyTask(new AtlassianModule("ch.mibex.bamboo.sonar4bamboo:sonar4bamboo.gradletask"))
                                    .description("Sonar Gradle")
                                    .configuration(new MapBuilder()
                                            .put("chosenSonarConfigId", "1")
                                            .put("useGradleWrapper", "true")
                                            .put("useNewGradleSonarQubePlugin", "true")
                                            .put("sonarJavaSource", "")
                                            .put("sonarProjectName", "")
                                            .put("buildJdk", "JDK")
                                            .put("gradleWrapperLocation", "${bamboo.build.working.directory}\\XYZ\\gradlew.bat")
                                            .put("sonarLanguage", "")
                                            .put("sonarSources", "")
                                            .put("useGlobalSonarServerConfig", "true")
                                            .put("failBuildForBrokenQualityGates", "")
                                            .put("sonarTests", "")
                                            .put("failBuildForSonarErrors", "")
                                            .put("sonarProjectVersion", "")
                                            .put("sonarBranch", "")
                                            .put("executable", "")
                                            .put("illegalBranchCharsReplacement", "_")
                                            .put("sonarJavaTarget", "")
                                            .put("environmentVariables", "")
                                            .put("replaceSpecialBranchChars", "")
                                            .put("additionalProperties", "")
                                            .put("autoBranch", "")
                                            .put("sonarProjectKey", "")
                                            .put("overrideSonarBuildConfig", "")
                                            .put("workingSubDirectory", "XYZ")
                                            .build()))
```

I think I need to use MapBuilder in kotlin but I don't know how to use it and all values

```
In kotlin

         AnyTask(AtlassianModule("ch.mibex.bamboo.sonar4bamboo:sonar4bamboo.gradletask"))
            .description("Sonar Gradle").configuration(MapBuilder()
              .put("chosenSonarConfigId", "1")
              .put("useGradleWrapper", "true")
              .put("useNewGradleSonarQubePlugin", "true")
              .put("sonarJavaSource", "")
              .put("sonarProjectName", "")
              .put("buildJdk", "JDK")
              .put("gradleWrapperLocation", "\${bamboo.build.working.directory}/gradlew.bat")
              .put("sonarLanguage", "")
              .put("sonarSources", "")
              .put("useGlobalSonarServerConfig", "true")
              .put("failBuildForBrokenQualityGates", "")
              .put("sonarTests", "")
              .put("failBuildForSonarErrors", "")
              .put("sonarProjectVersion", "")
              .put("sonarBranch", "")
              .put("executable", "")
              .put("illegalBranchCharsReplacement", "_")
              .put("sonarJavaTarget", "")
              .put("environmentVariables", "")
              .put("replaceSpecialBranchChars", "")
              .put("additionalProperties", "")
              .put("autoBranch", "")
              .put("sonarProjectKey", "")
              .put("overrideSonarBuildConfig", "")
              .put("workingSubDirectory", "")
              .build())
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It would be a good idea to include it in the question.

Comment: .configuration(MapBuilder() Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter K in 

constructor MapBuilder<K : Any!, V : Any!>
( )

Please specify it explicitly.

Comment: configuration(MapBuilder<String,String>().put...

Comment: What type does configuration expect?

Comment: @Sushant have a look at my answer, you should change the code like shown :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To solve that, you should specify the types, as suggested:

```
configuration(MapBuilder<String,String>().put...
```

But, there's a more straightforward way in Kotlin using its `mapOf`:

```
 mapOf("chosenSonarConfigId" to "1",
        "useNewGradleSonarQubePlugin" to "true",
        "sonarJavaSource" to "true"
         //...
)
```